# Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

there are a ton of SO postings on this subject.  by far, the solution seems to be to configure the directory in IIS as an application.  Another common solution is to remove backup web.config files from folders in the root.

my problem is different because I'm running on IIS Express so there's no way to configure the folder as an application.  what I've noticed is that every time I compile, there's a folder called **obj** in my root which causes the problem.  So I have to manually remove it, every time.

@Valamas, [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level) indicates he just scripted the removal of that folder but I'm thinking there's got to be a better way... the error occurs for me on this line:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

but seems to occur in other instances.  ideas anyone?

Comment: Far from being an elegant solution... as a stop gap, add to PostBuild event command line: `rd "$(ProjectDir)obj" /q /s`. In my test, it did not remove the folder or subfolders but did remove the files.

Comment: `rd "$(ProjectDir)obj" /q /s` (here is the command again on a single line)

Comment: thanks for the actual code :)

Comment: I still hope there's a better answer though.  there must be a reason for this

Answer (score 1):

You probably built the project under 'Release' and then reverted to 'Debug'. You should switch to 'Release' and perform Clean Solution: [section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712629/section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-l/6183612#6183612)

Comment: I've never used the **Release**, only **Debug**.  In fact, the problem doesn't seem to happen when I just build.  it happens when I go to publish (which requires a build)...