# C# ASP.NET MVC web.config and MachineToApplication error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two projects that is on iis like this:

```
inetpub/wwwroot/mysites/secure/web_application_1 --> has its own web.config

inetpub/wwwroot/mysites/secure/web_application_2 --> has its own web.config
```

The two applications are totally different applications, however, they both have their own client authentications & custom role & custom membership.

`web_application_1` works fine as its the old application.

`web_application_2` is the new application, when I ran it on the web, I got errors:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

I am not sure what is wrong in the `web.config`?

The `web.config` is same with the exception that:

- connection strings is different as they both uses different db
- custom membership & custom role is different as they both uses the namespace of the project

The whole IIS & URL was set up for web_application_1; and since it takes like forever to request new setup from my sysadmin, we both suggested i could just do this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/secure/web_application_1

inetpub/wwwroot/mysites/secure/web_application_1 --> has its own web.config
https://www.mywebsite.com/secure/web_application_2

inetpub/wwwroot/mysites/secure/web_application_2 --> has its own web.config
```

Comment: Well, if you have trouble with the `web.config` - then **PLEASE SHOW US** that file!! We can't see your screen, can't access your hard drive to have a look ourselves - post it here!

Comment: @marc_s I think i understand the problem I have, i would like to know if there is a work around it. so basically, i think the fact that these two applications are in the same "parent" folder, that is the error. i wonder if there is a work around it?

Comment: How are they configured in IIS. Is web_application_1 configured as a virtual directory or an application? What about web_application_2?

Comment: @Nate I just updated my post. i understand the error, the thing is, i don't know the solution? "mysites" is the directory, and web_application_1 is the application that runs the .net applications.

Comment: You might check this...[Article][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712629/section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application/19105006#19105006

Answer (score 2):

ok found my own solution:

Add the folder “web_application_2” as an application in IIS manager:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b5488995-fa99-460f-96d7-29d1ddcf3fac.mspx?mfr=true