# Other team members cannot compile the project

Tags: c#, tfs

I've created my account at visualstudio.com, created a new project, and added my team members.

Now, I've created a new website form from visual studio 2012, and then added it to the source control. So, the directory now is /MyProject/MyWebsite/

I can modify the project and run it through the browser. However, other team members cannot.

The steps follwed by a team member:
- Mapped the project to a local directory: D:/MyProject
- File > Open Website: /MyProject/
- I get this message:
IIS Express is already configuredd to serve pages from folder. do you want to open the site
using Visual Studio Development Server.....etc
- When I click Yes to use ISS:
- Solution Exploler > Default.aspx (Right click and open with Chrome), I get this error:

Error1:It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.   D:\MyProject\MyWebsite\Web.config 25

To summarize, the website uploader can view and run the code, while other member can only view it without being able to compile it as the shown error occurs.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I've got it working by creating a project rather than a website. Can I get a website to work?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712629/section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application

Comment: I've already looked into those threads. However, my problem seems to be different as I tried to apply many solutions but couldn't get it to work. The difference is that I use TFS.

Comment: did you check in the changes to tfs and asked other developers to get the latest version before testing it?

Comment: Yes. I've got it working by creating a project rather than a website.